# Как ставится ограничение скорости на скачивание файла?

Tags: http

Как ставят ограничение на скорость скачивания файла с сайта? Просто хотелось посмотреть подробное описание механизма этого.

Comment: Самый простой способ реализовать ограничение - считать объем исходящих пакетов за какой-то промежуток времени. Если объем пакетов превышает какой-то предел - тормозить их до следующего "кванта" времени.

Comment: так же можете посмотреть информацию о traffic shapping